# Additional network interface not configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using terraform to create an instance. This instance requires two additional network interfaces connecting to it. When running the code the resources build as expected and all seems good. Problem is the network interface is connected to the instance at a time where the instance does not recognise it. To get the interfaces to work the instance then has to be restarted. Is there a was of connecting the interface during the build so that the instance has three connections from the start?

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "VyOs_Windows_Interface" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.Windows_Access_Subnet[count.index].id
  private_ips     = ["10.0.2.101"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.Engineering[count.index].id]
  count           = var.Number
  depends_on = [aws_instance.VyOs[count.index].id,]

  attachment {
    instance     = aws_instance.VyOs[count.index].id
    device_index = 1
  }
```

Comment: Try the dedicated API endpoint with the resource at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_attachment instead of the network interface endpoint parameter. If that does not work, then there is a kind of ugly workaround for this problem, but give that a try first.

Comment: @MattSchuchard many thanks for the help. The resource you suggested is an improvement but unfortunately is very unreliable. Works, doesn't work, works on some items and not others. Will have to find a more reliable way of working.